# How do you get the current label dimensions setting for a zebra printer

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am making an access application that prints two sizes of label, 3" width by 2" height, and then 1.5" width by 1" height. This application will run on several different computers that dont have the same sets of printers, for example, machine 1 might have a GC420d, a GK420d and a regular 8.5x11 printer, then machine 2 might have a LP 2844, a GC420d, and a regular 8.5x11 printer. The machines are spread out across the production environment and we cant standardize on printer type. So, this leaves me where i need to be able to determine which printer has the 3" x 2" settings and which has the 1.5" by 1" setting.

EDIT: I know this looks like a "I havent tried anything and im too lazy to try" situation, but all of the code i had was lost when access crashed to desktop. I mostly tried Win API stuff like [DeviceCapabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Printing/programmatically-retrieve-printer-capabilities), but i couldn't get it to give me anything useful. a paper type Enumeration  of Custom is useless when i cant see what the actual dimensions of the custom paper type is. Then i tried [DocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/documentproperties) which required [OpenPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/openprinter) to get the printer handle. Thats the stuff that nuked everything access side. i used [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Windows-API/WIN32APITXTWin32APIDeclarationsforVisualBasic.htm)
website to get the API calls for VBA.

EDIT2: this is the return for the papertype according to access.

```
?application.Printers(0).DeviceName
ZDesigner GC420d (EPL)
?application.Printers(0).PaperSize
 256
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below to list all supported paper names and their corresponding sizes:

```
Private Enum DeviceCapabilitiesFlags
    DC_FIELDS = 1
    DC_PAPERS = 2
    DC_PAPERSIZE = 3
    DC_MINEXTENT = 4
    DC_MAXEXTENT = 5
    DC_BINS = 6
    DC_DUPLEX = 7
    DC_SIZE = 8
    DC_EXTRA = 9
    DC_VERSION = 10
    DC_DRIVER = 11
    DC_BINNAMES = 12
    DC_ENUMRESOLUTIONS = 13
    DC_FILEDEPENDENCIES = 14
    DC_TRUETYPE = 15
    DC_PAPERNAMES = 16
    DC_ORIENTATION = 17
    DC_COPIES = 18
    DC_BINADJUST = 19
    DC_EMF_COMPLIANT = 20
    DC_DATATYPE_PRODUCED = 21
    DC_COLLATE = 22
    DC_MANUFACTURER = 23
    DC_MODEL = 24
    DC_PERSONALITY = 25
    DC_PRINTRATE = 26
    DC_PRINTRATEUNIT = 27
    DC_PRINTERMEM = 28
    DC_MEDIAREADY = 29
    DC_STAPLE = 30
    DC_PRINTRATEPPM = 31
    DC_COLORDEVICE = 32
    DC_NUP = 33
    DC_MEDIATYPENAMES = 34
    DC_MEDIATYPES = 35
End Enum

Private Type POINT
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function DeviceCapabilities _
  Lib "winspool.drv" _
    Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesA" _
      (ByVal lpDeviceName As String, _
       ByVal lpPort As String, _
       ByVal iIndex As Long, _
       ByRef lpOutput As Any, _
       ByRef lpDevMode As Any) _
    As Long

Private Declare Function StrLen _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" _
    Alias "lstrlenA" _
      (ByVal lpString As String) _
    As Long

Public Sub ListSupportedPaperSizes()
    Dim defaultPrinter() As String
    Dim paperCount As Long
    Dim NameArray() As Byte
    Dim i As Long
    Dim paperNames() As String
    Dim paperName As String
    Dim ctr As Long

    defaultPrinter = Split(Application.ActivePrinter, " on ")
    paperCount = DeviceCapabilities(defaultPrinter(0), defaultPrinter(1), DC_PAPERSIZE, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&)
    ReDim paperNames(1 To paperCount)
    ReDim NameArray(0 To paperCount * 64) As Byte
    ' Get paper names
    paperCount = DeviceCapabilities(defaultPrinter(0), defaultPrinter(1), DC_PAPERNAMES, NameArray(0), 0)
   'convert the retrieved byte array to an ANSI string
    AllNames = StrConv(NameArray, vbUnicode)
    ReDim paperNames(1 To paperCount)
    'loop through the string and search for the names of the papers
    For i = 1 To Len(AllNames) Step 64
        ctr = ctr + 1
        paperName = Mid(AllNames, i, 64)
        paperName = Left(paperName, StrLen(paperName))
        If paperName <> vbNullString Then
            paperNames(ctr) = paperName
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim PaperSizes(1 To paperCount) As POINT
    paperCount = DeviceCapabilities(defaultPrinter(0), defaultPrinter(1), DC_PAPERSIZE, PaperSizes(1), 0)
    For i = 1 To paperCount
        Debug.Print paperNames(i) & " : " _
            & Format(PaperSizes(i).x / 254, "0.00") & " x " _
            & Format(PaperSizes(i).y / 254, "0.00") _
            & " inch"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Holy crap, as i was edting in the things ive tried, you pop up with an answer. The big problem i run into is that labels are not a standard paper size. They count as a custom paper size, i dont know what the custom paper size is though.

Comment: I saw you venting in Rubberducking but I don't have the rep to chat in there. See my edit.

Comment: I Appreciate you taking the time to go and look at it, I will try your code right now.

Comment: I had to make a couple of edits, but it works! The edit being, Access doesnt have `Application.ActivePrinter`, it just has `Application.Printer`, which i suppose is close to the same thing. so i replaced the bits where it said `DefaultPrinter(0)` with `Application.printer.devicename` and then 1 with port.

Comment: Happy to have helped a bit. Out of interest, what did you need to edit? It worked for me but I don't actually have a printer installed on this laptop - I just have Print to PDF as my default printer so IDK if that changed things.

Comment: Oh i also had to create a variable for `AllNames` but yeah, it found the dimensions, im so freaking excited that you came along with this answer, i cant even say.

Comment: Ah I should have added an `Option Explicit` to catch that. Happy to help. Thx for th + Rep